# WebStorm: make Live Edit work without debug mode

Tags: html, web, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, liveedit

There's a plugin in Visual Studio called Live Server. When you edit and save changes to an html/css file, you don't have to refresh the page if it's open in your browser, it refreshes automatically. Webstorm has similar functionality called Live Edit, but it works in debug mode only.

Also is it possible to make it work with Safari or at least another Chromium browser like Vivaldi, or corresponding extension works in Google Chrome only? Because Live Edit doesn't work without Google Chrome. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Live Edit didn't require debugging initially, but we had to re-consider this approach due to multiple bugs/limitations, see [WEB-8255](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-8255) and linked tickets. We are currently investigating a possibility to add "live reload" capability to the built-in web server to make it behave like VSCode Live Server.

We don't have plans to support Live Edit in Safari; to make it work with Vivaldi (or other Chrome-based browsers), you have to configure it in **Settings | Tools | Web Browsers:**

- In **Settings | Tools | Web Browsers**, press **+**
- Use *Chrome* as a **Family**, specify a full path to Vivaldi executable as **Path**, enter a name:

[image]